# Nested object assign Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have two objects like this:

```
var a = {prop:{a:'1'}}
var b = {prop:{b:'1'}}
```

I want to merge the two objects using Object.assign. I tried this:

```
var c = Object.assign(a,b)
> {prop:{b:'1'}}
```

How do I get this output:

```
{prop:{a:'1',b:'1'}}
```

In short, I want to do Object assign on every sub Objects => (IF PROPERTY EXISTS, CHECK CHILDREN FIRST IF IT AS OBJECT, DO NOT OVERIDE)

Comment: in above code, `c === a`, because of `Object.assign`. do you want a new object or assign to `a` ?

Comment: I want to merge them in a new object

Comment: There's no built-in function to recursively merge objects, but you could use `merge` from Lodash. https://lodash.com/docs#merge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a deep merge function for every level of the object.

The function `deepMerge` works as single function for a given target or as callback for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where an array of objects is iterated and an empty object is supplied as `startvalue` for reducing.

The function/callback itselft has two parameters, one for the target object and one for the source object where all entries are taken and iterated.

A value of the object is checked and if the type is an object, then a recursive call of `deepMerge` is done with a a new target property, if not given or to an exitent property.

If the value is not an object, the value is assigned to `target` with the given key.

The result is a new object with all properties of the given objects.

```js
function deepMerge(target, source) {
    Object.entries(source).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            deepMerge(target[key] = target[key] || {}, value);
            return;
        }
        target[key] = value;
    });
    return target;
}

var a = { prop: { a: '1' } },
    b = { prop: { b: '1' } },
    c = [a, b].reduce(deepMerge, {});
    
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Yes. But why? ;)

Comment: as i see it, op wants a deep merge of objects. actually js do not supot this out of the box. that's why you need to write an own merger wor arbitrary count of nestings and properties without knowing them in advance.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation ? (comments on the algorithm. I see you are using a nested function call)

Answer (score 2):

Since a and b in your case contains a property with same name, when you do something like `Object.assign(a,b)`the `prop` property of b overwrites and not merge the prop. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Syntax)

Try the following:

```js
var a = {prop:{a:'1'}}
var b = {prop:{b:'1'}}

var c = {};
c.prop = Object.assign({},a.prop,b.prop);

console.log(c);
```

Or

You can write your own custom function which can merge the values of the objects with same properties.

Try the following:

```js
function merge(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach((k) => {
        if (source[k].constructor.toString().indexOf('Object') > -1 && target[k]) {          
            merge(source[k], target[k]);
            return;
        }
        target[k] = source[k];
    });
    return target;
}

var a = {prop:{a: '1'}};
var b = {prop:{ b: '1'}};
var c = {};
[a,b].forEach((e)=>merge(e, c));
    
console.log(c);
```

Comment: that works only for a single (and know upper) level.

Comment: @NinaScholz op has edited the question just now only :-)

Comment: can you add a bit of explanations please?

Comment: The first argument is the `target`, the rest are `sources` – See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Syntax