# How to merge multiple objects into one?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am looking for a way to merge many objects with the same key to a one big object. The number of objects can be more that 2.

For example I have this code:

```
const a = {
  en: {
    hello: 'Hello'
  },

  fr: {
    hello: 'Bonjour'
  }
}

const b = {
  en: {
    goodbye: 'Goodbye'
  },

  fr: {
    goodbye: 'Au revoir'
  }
}
```

How to merge that into this:

```
{
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en: {
      hello: 'Hello',
      goodbye: 'Goodbye'
    },

    fr: {
      hello: 'Bonjour',
      goodbye: 'Au revoir'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what qualifies `locale: 'en'`?

Comment: maybe a look worth: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52131927

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested object assign Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52131927/nested-object-assign-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a deep merge function for every level of the object.

The function `deepMerge` works as single function for a given target or as callback for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where an array of objects is iterated and an empty object is supplied as `startvalue` for reducing.

As result, you need a new object and assign the merges objects as new property `messages`.

```js
function deepMerge(target, source) {
    Object.entries(source).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            deepMerge(target[key] = target[key] || {}, value);
            return;
        }
        target[key] = value;
    });
    return target;
}

var a = { en: { hello: 'Hello' }, fr: { hello: 'Bonjour' } },
    b = { en: { goodbye: 'Goodbye' }, fr: { goodbye: 'Au revoir' } },
    c = { locale: 'en', messages: [a, b].reduce(deepMerge, {}) };
    
console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Function mergeArray for array merging

```
const mergeArray = (firstArray, secondArray) => {
  return {
    locale: 'en',
    messages: {
      en: {
          ...firstArray.en,
          ...secondArray.en
      },
      fr: {
        ...firstArray.fr,
        ...secondArray.fr
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(mergeArray(a, b));
```

Below snippets give you expected output.

```
const value = { locale: 'en', messages: { en: { ...a.en, ...b.en }, fr: { ...a.fr, ...b.fr } }};
console.log(value)
```

Comment: I have implemented the same in the function.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to a new object, you can use Object.Assign({}, a, b)

read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: update it to be into new object, Object.Assign({}, a, b) @Attersson

Comment: And the second edit creates a new object, in contrast to OP request to merge `a` into the second object. No no.

Comment: @Attersson - The fact that `a` is a `const` has nothing whatsoever to do with whether you can modify the object it refers to. You can. (That doesn't make this a good answer, but thought I'd mention it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are correct, I mean it is supposedly not the target of the final merge (and therefore the non mutating one), in OP intent and the original version of this answer still had them swapped

Answer (score -1):

Try this when the number of objects is dynamic:

```
var o, k, v, n, A=[a,b], r={}
for(o in A) for(k in A[o]) if(!r[k]) r[k]={};
for(o in A) for(v in A[o]) for(n in A[o][v]) if(!r[v][n]) r[v][n]= A[o][v][n];
console.log(r);
console.log({locale: 'en',messages:r});
```

Comment: in my old answers, i supposed that the number of objects is 2. please check my updated answer.